# Filter union types based on existence of character

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to solve for `???` so that `AlphaFoo` is 'foo' ?

```
type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar1' | '213'
type Predicate = '1'
type FilterIfContains<Element, Predicate> = ???
type AlphaFoo = FilterIfContains<Foo, Predicate>; // expect 'foo'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
type Foo = 'foo' | 'bar1' | '213'
type Predicate = '1'
type FilterIfContains<Element, Predicate extends string> = Exclude<Element, `${string}${Predicate}${string}`>
type AlphaFoo = FilterIfContains<Foo, Predicate>; // 'foo'
```